# How can I pin the toolbar so that it remains revealed?

Tags: application-development, qml, ubuntu-sdk

An always-revealed toolbar would be more suitable for a [pointer-driven interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337665/how-do-i-detect-the-presence-of-a-mouse-or-touchpad). How, using the Ubuntu SDK, can I set the toolbar to be (and remain) revealed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a bug in the Ubuntu UI toolkit discussing whether this should be implemented by default. However, it currently must be done manually.

This is what I use:

```
onActiveChanged: tools.opened = showToolbar

tools: ToolbarItems {
    locked: showToolbar
    opened: showToolbar
}
```

Unfortunately, there is a bug in the SDK that causes a  2gu margin above the toolbar. I fix that by adding this to my `MainView`:

```
states: [
    State {
        when: showToolbar

        PropertyChanges {
            target: taskViewPage.parent
            anchors.bottomMargin: -root.toolbar.triggerSize
        }
    }
]
```