# How can I anchor a component to the top of the toolbar?

Tags: application-development, qml, ubuntu-sdk

Using the Ubuntu SDK, how can I get an anchor to the top of the toolbar?

I want something like this:

```
MyItem {
    anchors.bottom: toolbar.top
}
```

so that I can anchor an item to an [omnipresent toolbar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337675/how-can-i-pin-the-toolbar-so-that-it-remains-revealed) in a way that is suitable for a [pointer-driven interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337665/how-do-i-detect-the-presence-of-a-mouse-or-touchpad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the toolbar is locked and opened, the contents of the `MainView` are automatically anchored to the top of the toolbar. However, there is a bug in the SDK which causes a 2gu margin above the toolbar. I fix it by adding the following to `MainView`:

```
states: [
    State {
        when: showToolbar

        PropertyChanges {
            target: taskViewPage.parent
            anchors.bottomMargin: -root.toolbar.triggerSize
        }
    }
]
```